# Ginger bug stopped bubbling so I added some yeast

Tags: ginger-beer, ginger

I had a healthy ginger bug for the first 4 days which was bubbling away nicely until it all stopped for no apparent reason. I kept feeding it as per normal and it didn't do anything for another 4 days.
I decided that I would give it a "kick start" and feed it some yeast to get it back into life which has worked along with regular feeding.

My question is will this be fine to use and is it still technically a ginger bug or should I give up and try again?

Starter Recipe below
2 Cups water 
2 Tablespoons ginger
2 Tablespoons Sugar

Feeding daily
1 Tablespoons ginger
1 Tablespoons Sugar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, still a ginger bug. Sometimes they need a little help, 4 days is not enough for all the critters in your bug to die, most likely it got cold or there was a sudden drop in temp one day and the bug became dormant. You did the right thing priming it with a bit of extra yeast.

Some of the bacteria or yeasts may have died off, but with you regularly adding in fresh chopped ginger they will get reintroduced and a balanced bug will rebuild itself.